# JavaScript DOM style.backgroundColor not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, dom, onclick, dom-events

My problem is as it follows:

I have a piece of JavaScript code which generates a "new" document using `document.write` and at first I write the entire heading of the web page. In that head I have a bit of CSS code which looks like this:

```
<style type='text/css'> 
.black {background-color: black;} 
.white {background-color: #ffffff;} 
td {width:50px; height:50px;} 
</style>
```

And JavaScript draws a table in the body section. Writing code is basically two `for` loops which draw a chess board. But that doesn't even matter. Every `td` element gets a class `black` or `white` by which it gets properly coloured. And every `td` gets a `onclick='changeBg(this)'` attribute.

Here is where the problem comes to life. I can not access the background color of the element that gets clicked. Function looks like so:

```
function changeBg(element)
{
    alert(element.style.backgroundColor);
    element.style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
```

At first I alert the color of the current element. It always alerts a blank notification. After I change the color to red and click on the element again it alerts `red`. The `td`'s are coloured in the browser and if I inspect them with firebug the have `background-color: black | white`;

What am I missing and how to fix this? I have realised that if I set `td` color when creating them using `style="color: black | white"`; it works but then I don't know to which class they belong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can get the *currently applied style* using `window.getComputedStyle` - [Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.getComputedStyle)

```
function changeBg(element) {
    alert(window.getComputedStyle(element).backgroundColor);
    element.style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
```